# How to remove multiple characters in a string in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to remove characters in a string in SQL.  The nomenclature that is currently in the database looks like this:

Engine - Brand - Category

How can I remove everything and only leave the 'category' portion?

Funnily enough, the code I've been currently using has been doing the opposite of what I want.  It's keeping everything and removing the 'category' portion.  I've tried leading, both, and trailing and still get the same results

```
select trim(Both'-' from SUBSTRING_INDEX(ad_group,'- ',2)) 
from farm.GoogleAdGroup GAG
join farm.GoogleCampaign GC on GAG.googlecampaign_id_fk = GC.id
where campaign_type like 'product'
limit 50;
```

I just need the code to keep the 'category' section and remove everything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like  below

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX('Engine - Brand - Category','-',-1)
```

it will return `Category`

so in your case

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(ad_group,'-',-1)
```

Comment: I think that did it! Thank you so much!